# Dragabbale won't move in react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm trying to build a simple implementation of draggables in `react-beautiful-dnd` but apparently my draggables won't move.

Here is my sample code in CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/using-react-beautiful-dnd-with-hooks-zqpi9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `style` attribute from child of `draggable` (in your case it's `Block` component). DnD uses its own `style` attribute and you override it. You have to use `className` instead of it.

Your example without `style`:
https://codesandbox.io/s/using-react-beautiful-dnd-with-hooks-1m4zm